# No water coming out of the kitchen faucet. Only a couple drops when cold or hot water is turned on

Tags: kitchens, faucet

We had a hard freeze here in Louisiana last week. We are back to warmer temperatures outside now 71•degrees. All my faucets and showers are able to run water except for my kitchen sink faucet. My dishwasher even works. Just one single drip of water every 5 seconds out of my kitchen sink faucet. What could be the problem?

Comment: Sink pipes might just be in a cold spot that is not heating up as fast.  Would leave the taps open to keep dripping, the drips will speed up opening the pipes.

Comment: I’ve had the tabs open for two days thinking the same thing but no change so far. I have a pull out type of faucet. I know it’s probably something so simple It is driving me crazy lol. But thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dishwasher works and it's next to the sink, that's great!   It means the water is almost there.

I'd wager the freezing and thawing of pipes dislodged some sediment and it's clogging up the screen and aerator on the tip of your faucet.   Unscrew it to see if water comes out.

**Be careful not to drop the parts down the drain.**